# How to activate each event once using on()/off()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Requirements:

1. Clicking on the same radio button should not fire the event more than once.
2. We can move between the radio buttons many times.

```js
$(function(){

    function teacher(){
        $(this).off('click');
        console.log('teacher off');
    }

    function student(){
        $(this).off('click');
        console.log('student off');
    }

    $('#teacher').on('click', teacher); 
    $('#teacher').click(function(){
        $('#student').on('click', student);
        console.log('student on');      
    });

    $('#student').on('click', student);
    $('#student').click(function(){
        $('#teacher').on('click', teacher);
        console.log('teacher on');      
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="student" name="school" value="student" checked>Student
<input type="radio" id="teacher" name="school" value="teacher">Teacher
```

The console log in this code doesn't give me the following pattern:

teacher off, student on

student off, teacher on

See my question in the title.

Comment: This looks like a very convoluted way to do something. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand what's the expected behavior

Comment: Just use .one() instead of .on()

Comment: append and remove input fields inside a form (console log is just for testing).

Comment: @j08691 , with one() it's still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more-elegant way to handle this would be to use the `change` event with [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). This way we don't have to keep unbinding and rebinding event listeners to the individual radio buttons.

```js
$(document).on('change', '[name="school"]', function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    console.log('Do something with: ', selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="student" name="school" value="student" checked>Student
<input type="radio" id="teacher" name="school" value="teacher">Teacher
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire event only once, you want to use `.one()`:

```
$('#student').one('click', student);
```

[jQuery .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. **The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.**

Comment: with one() it's still the same

Comment: Your question is not very clear then... http://jsfiddle.net/08vdv59m/ - is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: no, because in your code I can fire the event more than once.